# How do you assert that the current row in WINDOW is the last row?

Tags: sql, hive, amazon-athena, presto

If I have a query with a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` how can I get output for total rows in this window, or, the last row as a boolean?

I'd like to create two columns in the results with a boolean for both the first and last rows in the window.

```
A | ROW_NUMBER
---
1 | 1
2 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 1


TO

A | ROW_NUMBER | FIRST | LAST
---
1 | 1 | 1 | 1
2 | 1 | 1 | 0
2 | 2 | 0 | 1
3 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `FIRST_VALUE`:

```
SELECT A, row_num, 
 CASE WHEN FIRST_VALUE(row_num) OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY row_num) = row_num 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS first_row,
 CASE WHEN FIRST_VALUE(row_num) OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY row_num DESC)=row_num 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS last_row  
FROM tab
ORDER BY a, row_num;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3c053684ce77c9d5a273d0b01c1afa59)**

Output:

```
+----+----------+------------+----------+
| a  | row_num  | first_row  | last_row |
+----+----------+------------+----------+
| 1  |       1  |         1  |        1 |
| 2  |       1  |         1  |        0 |
| 2  |       2  |         0  |        1 |
| 3  |       1  |         1  |        1 |
+----+----------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Like the usage of `FIRST_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the total count:

```
COUNT(*) OVER ...
```

You can also do:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (.... ORDER BY ... DESC)
```

Ordering in descending order means 1 = your last record

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
select 
  a,
  row_number,
  case ra = 1 then 1 else 0 end as first,
  case rd = 1 then 1 else 0 end as last
from (
  select
    a,
    row_number,
    row_number() over(partition by a order by row_number) as ra,
    row_number() over(partition by a order by row_number desc) as rd
  from my_table
) x
order by a
```

Comment: Seems so obvious when you put it like that! Cheers.